Loop Effect of $\phi$ Propagator in $t$-channel of scalar $\phi^3$ theory
In Schwartz's QFT chapter 16, he calculates the loop effect (vaccum polarization) of $\phi$ propagator in $\phi^3$ theory, with the choice of Pauli-Villars regulator, the scattering amplitude would be
$$
\mathcal{M}_{\text{loop}}(p) = \frac{g^2}{32\pi^2}\left[2-\ln(\frac{-p^2}{\Lambda^2})\right]\;.\tag{16.11}
$$
By redefining $\Lambda^2\rightarrow\Lambda^2e^{-2}$, and he mentions that when $t$-channel (or computing the Coulomb potential), the virtual momentum $p^{\mu}$ is spacelike ($p^2<0$), thus $\ln(\frac{-p^2}{\Lambda^2})$ is real, and rewrite (16.11) $Q^2 = -p^2$,
$$\mathcal{M}_{\text{loop}}(p) = -\frac{g^2}{32\pi^2}\ln(\frac{Q^2}{\Lambda^2}).\tag{16.12}$$
My question is, what is the loop effect of $\phi$ propagator in $s$-channel, where the virtual momentum $p$ is no longer spacelike $(p^2>0)$, then the logarithm should be ill-defined?
I suppose after choosing a renormalization condition, the minus sign would cannel and there is no problem, but I wonder if this is a correct concept?

Comment to the post (v2): Schwartz is discussing vacuum polarization; not $2\to 2$ scattering with $s$ & $t$ channels.

@Qmechanic But he claims in the calculation of vacuum polarization that the virtual momentum is spacelike, then how the statement works?

You can choose a branch cut to evaluate the negative log if I remember correctly e.g. $\log(-x) = \log(|x|) + i \pi$. The imaginary part is related to the virtual particles going on shell. This is a special case of the optical theorem. Exercise 16.3 works through an S-channel example.
Source: My memory from when I took the class
